# Cocos2d+ViewController=EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access, viewcontroller

I have a problem. I call this function:

```
- (void)createComposeViewController:(NSString *)serviceType {
__block SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:serviceType];

if (controller == nil) return;

[controller setInitialText:@"I like appname!")];
[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appstore.com/appname"]];
[controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];
controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
NSLog(@"Cancelled");
} else {
NSLog(@"send message to social");
}

[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And it is working right. But if i don't close field of message and minimize application, then i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in CCGLView.m in 275-st line:

```
if(![context_ presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER])
```

I don't know why.
This error I get at iPad 3. I don't have other devices.

And I get this in emulator:

```
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
```

but an application working.

The same is happening with other ViewController, for example with GKLeaderboardViewController

If create new project, then all working without any errors with the same conditions.
What's I do wrong?

cocos2d v2.1-beta4 IOS6.1

Comment: I found the problem. If delete this line:

[CDAudioManager sharedManager];

Then it's working right.
How I will can use a sound?

This is test project: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0B2FkmHQpfUOFJ4SnpKbGJyYlE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use app delegate instead of director

```
SLComposeViewController*fvc = [SLComposeViewController
                                       composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fvc setInitialText:desc];
        [fvc addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgPath]];
        [fvc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            [myDelegate.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }];

        AppController * myDelegate = (((AppController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));

        [myDelegate.navController presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:^{
        }];
```